# Getting the number of days between two dates

Tags: php, date, datetime, time

I have a PHP application in which i have to compare between two dates

```
$interval = date("Y-m-d",time()) - date("2013-07-1");
```

However, it always returns `0` as value for `$interval`.

How can I modify the code to fix the problem?

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/date `date()` returns a **STRING**, so you're doing the equivalent of `'apple' - 'orange'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try DateTime instead. Sample code here

```
<?PHP
    $datetime1 = date_create('2013-07-3');
    $datetime2 = date_create();
    $interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
    echo $interval->format('%D %M %Y');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using PHP >= 5.2, try using the DateTime class:

```
$interval = date_diff(new DateTime(), new DateTime('2013-07-3'));
$days = $interval->days;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is always best to work in datetime values - integer representation of second since (i think) 01/01/1970?

Anyway, Muhammed is pretty much correct, except I don't think you want to change your result back to a date.

Stick to:

```
$interval=time()-strtotime("2013-07-1");
// $interval will therefore hold the number of seconds difference between the dates.
```

Divide $interval by 60, 3600, (24*3600) to get minutes, hours or days.

Comment: It's not best to work with timestamps, as they may present strange issues when the current timezone is using DST (when certain days can last 23 or 25 hours)